# Schedule Exe in Every 30 minutes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to schedule Exe in every 30 minutes in C#.Please help me how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

You can use timers: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398865(v=vs.140).aspx Just set interval to 1800000 (30 minutes)